# Simple Binary Search Tree Class with Insert and Search Functions

Tags: c++, object-oriented, binary-search, binary-tree

I am trying to learn to implement DSs in C++ and here is a simple implementation. Please review in terms of optimization, memory management, coding standards, etc

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

class BstNode{
int data;
BstNode* left;
BstNode* right;

public:
BstNode(int data)
{
    this->data = data;
    this->left = NULL;
    this->right = NULL;
}
~BstNode();

void Insert(int data)
{
    if(this->data >= data)
    {
        if (this->left == NULL)
            this->left = new BstNode(data);
        else 
            this->left->Insert(data);
    }
    else
    {
        if (this->right == NULL)
            this->right = new BstNode(data);
        else 
            this->right->Insert(data);
    }
}

bool Search(int data)
{
    if(this->data == data)
        return true;
    else if(this->data >= data)
    {
        if(this->left == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            return this->left->Search(data);
    }
    else
    {
        if(this->right == NULL)
            return false;
        else
            return this->right->Search(data);
    }

}
};

int main()
{
BstNode* ptr_root = new BstNode(15);
ptr_root->Insert(10);
ptr_root->Insert(16);
int num;
std::cout<<"Enter the number: \n";
std::cin>> num;
if (ptr_root->Search(num))
    std::cout<<"Found\n";
else
    std::cout<<"Not Found\n";

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The code in search is broken for a number of reasons. This question is off-topic because it can't work in many situations. You might want to enable warning messages in your compile, the warning I got was `'BstNode::Search': not all control paths return a value`.

Comment: @pacmaninbw I used onlineGDB and it compiled without any issues. Can you please tell what you're using so that I can try to reproduce the error?

Comment: I'm using Visual Studio 2019 installed locally on my computer.

Comment: @pacmaninbw corrected the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Overall organization

Right now, you've defined a `BstNode`, which you use directly in `main`. I'd at least consider defining a `Bst` class, and then (probably inside that) a `Node` class.

```
class Bst {
    class Node {
        // only code to deal with individual nodes goes here
    };

    Node *root;
public:

    bool insert(int value);

    bool find(int value);
};
```

Then to create a Binary search tree, you'd just instantiate a `Bst` object, and use it:

```
int main() {

    Bst tree;

    // oops--this will lead to a completely imbalanced tree.
    for (int i=0; i<10; i++)
        tree.insert(i);

}
```

## in-class initialization

Since you (almost?) always create a node with its child pointers set to nullptrs, I'd just specify that directly in the class instead of in the ctor:

```
// ...
class Node {
    int value;
    Node *left = nullptr;
    Node *right = nullptr;

    Node(int value) : value(value) {}
};
```

## Insertion and Search

I'd at least consider whether you really want to use recursion to do insertion and/or search. Since you only ever descend to one child of any given node, it's pretty easy to use iteration for these tasks.

## Insert return type

I'd at least consider having `Insert` return a bool to indicate whether it actually inserted a value in the tree or not (e.g., return false if a value is already present).

## Collection type

What you've currently implemented is roughly equivalent to a `std::set`. That is, it stores only keys. This can certainly be useful, but there are times its also useful to have data associated with the key (i.e., roughly equivalent to `std::map`).

## Generic Code

Right now, you've written the code so the only thing can be stored in your BST is `int`s. I'd at least consider making it generic so other types can be stored.

```
template <class T, class Cmp = std::less<T>>
class Bst {
    // ...
```

This increases complexity a little, but increases functionality quite a lot.

Answer (score 4):

This program is using purely C++ I/O so the include for the old style C I/O is not necessary, you don't need the `#include <stdio.h>` and it would be better to remove it.

The indentation of the code is inconsistent and confusing, both in the class and in the `main()` function.

Generally in C++ it is unnecessary to use the `this` pointer, it is required in only two places in the code and wouldn't be necessary at all if the name of the input variable was changed.

```
    BstNode(int data)
    {
        this->data = data;
        left = NULL;
        right = NULL;
    }


    bool Search(int data)
    {
        if(this->data == data)
            return true;
        else if(data >= data)
        {
            if(left == nullptr)
                return false;
            else
                return left->Search(data);
        }
        else
        {
            if(right == nullptr)
                return false;
            else
                return right->Search(data);
        }

    }
```

In modern C++ one should use `nullptr` rather than NULL as shown above.